# getModel() vs getModelMap() in ModelAndView

Tags: spring-mvc

Which one has to be used when ?

When I see the source code of `ModelAndView` class, `getModel()` is simpling calling the `getModelMap()`, Why are there two different methods doing same activity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backwards compatibility. Earlier versions of Spring only had `getModel()`, newer versions added the more explicit `getModelMap()`. Note that the return type is slightly different also, `getModelMap()` returns the more tightly typed `ModelMap` class, rather than a raw pre-java5 `Map`.